# Process Each Row in Kettle ONE AT A TIME?

Tags: pentaho, jobs, synchronous, kettle

I was wondering if it is possible to work on a per row basis in the kettle?

I am trying to implement a reporting scheme which consists of a table, where the requests get queued for processing and then the Pentaho job that picks up the records on that table.

my job currently has 3 transformations in it,

1st is to get records from the queued requests table

2nd is to analyze the values on each record and come up with multiple results based on that record. for example, a user would request to have records of movies of the horror genre. then it should spit out the horror movies

3rd is to further retrieve the information about the movies such as the year, director and etc, which is to be outputted to an excel file.

this is the idea, but it's a bit challenging doing it in Pentaho as it does stuff all at the same. is there a way that I can make my job work on records one by one?

EDIT.

Just to add, I have been trying to extend the implementation of the Pentaho cookbook sample but if I compare to my design, its like step 2 and step 3 only.

I can't seem to make the table input step work one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just made it act like the implementation in the cookbook, i did adjustments on it. instead of using two transformations to gather all the necessary fields, i just retrieved all the information that i need in 1 transformation.

then after that i copied those information to the next steps, then some queries to complete the information and it is now working.

passing parameters between transformations is a bit confusing, there are parameters to be set on the transformation itself and also on the job where the transformations lay so i kinda went guessing for some time just to make it work.